# What do I lose if I move from R to Python?

Tags: python, r

I am intermediate in R and a beginner in Python. However my core abilities lie less in data analysis and more in programming and developing large software systems in teams, and I don't have time to become an expert in both.

Given the advances in the Python world in numpy, scipy, pandas, and its prevalence in data science and in general programming, I think I need to concentrate on Python (even though I enjoy R a lot), and accept that for some tasks I might be 75% as efficient, say, as I would be in R. I'd find this efficiency loss acceptable in order to be a master of one language rather than intermediate at both.

However I don't know enough about either language to really be sure of my facts. I would be very interested in hearing from anyone who is experienced in both R and Python and can say what would be the *significant* disadvantages, if any, of dropping R in favour of Python?

Edit 5: [this question on stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/python-as-a-statistics-workbench) is similar and has some great answers.

(Edits 3-4: reverted content/title to original question, which was closed. The original question attracted a lot of expert comment, my attempt to narrow the question to reopen it failed, and I'd prefer to have these comments below the original text they were commenting on.)

Comment: For a question aking for an opinion, [here](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/R-and-pandas-and-what-ive-learned-about-each.html) is an opinionated answer...

Comment: @Colt45 thanks that looks interesting. I was hoping for that someone might reply from experience, e.g. "I used Python and whilst it was good overall, we found it time consuming to do xyz which was really easy in R [because R had a package for it, or whatever]".

Comment: The vast array of R packages would be the major missing feature if you switched to Python, presuming of course that it is either-or. Your question will likely be subject to closure as it is essentially asking for peoples' opinions.

Comment: The question's probably too subjective and might get closed, but to give you a short answer: plotting capabilities. `matplotlib` is good, but it can't touch `ggplot2`, `lattice`, or probably even the base graphics system.

Comment: @Marius You mean "put on hold"? ;)

Comment: @joran smart arse ;-)

Comment: If you look around, you'll see other people _have_ had this dilemma, and some of them have come up with schemes to use R from Python

Comment: Since tools such as `rpy` or passing data through JSON or CSV, are, though not polished, more or less guaranteed to produce a working program *eventually*, there is not likely to be any show-stopper. If you are concerned about waking up next month and thinking "oh snap I forgot we couldn't live without X", I would say you are safe on that point. The same is largely true of switching the other way.

Comment: @Marius Thanks, that's the sort of thing I was looking for. Your comment along with the others are valuable in my opinion. Your comment and others _did_ reference specific facts and it didn't look like this would be a bun fight. It's a shame, but not that surprising, that it's on hold: I'll have a think and see if I can get it reopened but nothing jumps out at me (I thought about Programmers but this has had 5 R questions this year).